# Як правильно: "торговий центр", "торгівельний центр" чи "торговельний центр"?

Tags: граматика, spelling, прикметники, орфографія

Якщо проаналізувати назви магазинів та центрів, то можна знайти різні написання:

1. ТЦ на Петровці - **Торгівельний** центр "Городок".
2. Товарна біржа "Всеукраїнський **торгівельний** центр".
3. **Торгівельний** центр «Дастор» у місті Ужгород.
4. **Торговий** центр — Вікіпедія.
5. **Торговельний** центр Європорт Европорт.
6. **Торговельний** центр Dubai Marina Mall - Visit Dubai.

Яке написання ТЦ є правильним?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Пошук у словнику:

В [словнику](http://sum.in.ua) знаходимо тільки ці два слова:

[Торговий](http://sum.in.ua/s/torghovyj) і [торговельний](http://sum.in.ua/s/torghoveljnyj).

Слова торгівельний немає.

#### Детальний розбір:

[Словесники славутича](https://movlitslav.jimdo.com/%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA/%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%87%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B3%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9/) роблять докорінний розбір цього питання:

1. Визнають, що офіційними є *торговий* і *торговельний*.
2. Порівнюють словотвір з наступними словами:

> ...інші слова на -івля, які утворені подібним до слова торгівля способом (торгувати - торгівля). Є, наприклад, слова годівля (від слова годувати) і будівля (від будувати). Помічаємо, що прикметники, утворені від них, зберігають звук [і] у відкритому складі: будівельний, годівельний. Тобто словотвірна модель, за якою утворились слова будівельний, годівельний, вимагає писати торгівельний, а не торговельний.

3. Наводять контрарґумент Авраменко

> що в цьому слові другий склад закритий, і ділити слово треба так: тор - гів - ля.

Тоді треба користатися наступним правилом:

> у коренях спільнокореневих слів звук [і], який був у закритому складі, у ситуації, коли цей склад відкритий, чергується зі звуком [О].

4. Проводять аналіз згідно теорії [гучності](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4_(%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE)#.D0.A2.D0.B5.D0.BE.D1.80.D1.96.D1.97_.D0.BF.D1.80.D0.BE_.D0.BF.D1.80.D0.B8.D1.80.D0.BE.D0.B4.D1.83_.D1.81.D0.BA.D0.BB.D0.B0.D0.B4.D1.83), який виявляє, що ділити слово треба все-таки як `тор-гів-ля`.
5. Таким чином, склад закритий, і дійсно треба писати  *торговельний*.

#### Цікавий коментар Пономарева:

Професор Пономарів окремо [звертає увагу](https://www.bbc.com/ukrainian/blogs/2014/12/141222_ponomariv_blog40_ko) на цікавий феномен, який поки лише цікавий і не має стосунку до того, як зараз правильно писати це слово:

> Як потрібно казати: торговельний чи торгівельний. За законом закритих
> і відкритих складів має бути торгів-ля, але торго-вельний, ко-за –
> кіз-ка, но-га – ніж-ка. Проте в ході словотворення спостерігаємо
> відступ від цього закону: кізонька, ніженька – замість очікуваних
> козонька, ноженька. З'явилися купівельний від купівля, заготівельний
> від заготівля. Через це поряд із торговельний маємо вже й
> торгівельний. Останній варіянт, на мою думку, згодом набуде більшого
> поширення.

Comment: Що характерно, пояснення Пономарева та Авраменка мають ряд помилок.

Comment: @PaulGor я думаю, додаткова відповідь - завжди добре для повнішого розуміння. Я із задоволенням поставлю стрілочку вгору)

Comment: первісно слово тър.го.влꙗ (та подібні до нього) не мало умов для переходу о>і, тоді як у слова тър.гô.вль.нъ.и (і подібних) такі умови були, тому форми торгів(е)льний, будів(е)льний, купів(е)льний є цілком виправдані історично (тут звук (е) є вставним, для полегшення вимови; він з'явився в цих словах вже після переходу о>і). Натомість, саме форми будівля, купівля, покрівля, торгівля (з і замість о) є вторинними й виникли під дією аналогії.
Щодо форми торговельний (з о), то я вбачаю тут найпізніший вплив аналогії від слів торговий, торговиця.